# How to access specific path in linux using shellscript

Tags: linux, shell, dynamic, scripting

Let us consider an example,

**scriptPath=/home/sharath/Downloads/Atollic_TrueSTUDIO_for_STM32_9.2.0_installer**

In the above line of code, If user is "sharath" then he can access a file/folder same way if the user is different how can access that folder/file dynamically.

below is my shellscript(.sh file):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu
configLocation=/etc/atollic
scriptPath=/home/sharath/Downloads/Atollic_TrueSTUDIO_for_STM32_9.2.0_installer
family=STM32
arch=x86_64
version=9.2.0
configFile=${configLocation}/TrueSTUDIO_for_${family}_${arch}_${version}.properties
installPath=/opt/Atollic_TrueSTUDIO_for_${family}_${arch}_${version}/ 
mkdir -p /opt/Atollic_TrueSTUDIO_for_STM32_x86_64_9.2.0/
tar xzf ${scriptPath}/install.data -C /opt/Atollic_TrueSTUDIO_for_STM32_x86_64_9.2.0/
```

In last line of the script, ${scriptPath} is diffrent for diffrent user, how can handle in shell script.

Update 1:

if i use, ${USER} or ${HOME} or whoami which returns "root" ,
Here is my log:

```
tar (child): /root/Downloads/Atollic_TrueSTUDIO_for_STM32_9.2.0_installer/install.data: Cannot open: No such file or directory tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Update 2:

Currently user in "root"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with couple of way and finally i found with below solution- 
Use below script for the

```
users
myuser=$(users)

echo "The user is " $myuser
```

Here ***users*** returns current user name.

Your script become:

```
#!/bin/bash
users
myuser=$(users)
set -eu
configLocation=/etc/atollic
scriptPath=/home/$myuser/Downloads/Atollic_TrueSTUDIO_for_STM32_9.2.0_installer
family=STM32
arch=x86_64
version=9.2.0
configFile=${configLocation}/TrueSTUDIO_for_${family}_${arch}_${version}.properties
installPath=/opt/Atollic_TrueSTUDIO_for_${family}_${arch}_${version}/ 
mkdir -p /opt/Atollic_TrueSTUDIO_for_STM32_x86_64_9.2.0/
tar xzf ${scriptPath}/install.data -C /opt/Atollic_TrueSTUDIO_for_STM32_x86_64_9.2.0/
```

Thanks for answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

Use $HOME for the start of scriptPath, i.e:

`scriptPath=${HOME}/Downloads/Atollic_TrueSTUDIO_for_STM32_9.2.0_installer`

Comment: hey, if is use ${HOME} or ${USER}, it will gives root, here is my log -  tar (child): /root/Downloads/Atollic_TrueSTUDIO_for_STM32_9.2.0_installer/install.data: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: I'm guessing this is because you are running the script as root? Try running it as the real user, eg sharath

Comment: just be aware, the `users` command doesn't actually return the current user, but **all** currently logged in users, It may not be a probem in your case if only one user is logged in at a time, just keep it in mind.

Comment: i got your point... i will do with multiple user and let you know..., Thanks

Answer (score -1):

What is the Linux OS you are using?

You can simply use as below,

scriptPath=~/Downloads/Atollic_TrueSTUDIO_for_STM32_9.2.0_installer

where ~ refers to the home directory of the user. i.e. /home/sarath

One other way is to use it like below,

scriptPath="/home/`whoami`/Downloads/Atollic_TrueSTUDIO_for_STM32_9.2.0_installer"

Comment: hey, if is use ${HOME} or ${USER} or whoami                                                        it will gives root, here is my log -                                                                                tar (child): /root/Downloads/Atollic_TrueSTUDIO_for_STM32_9.2.0_installer/install.data: Cannot open: No such file or directory tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Looks like you have logged in as the root user? what is the output of the id command or whoami in the shell?

Or are you executing the script with sudo?

Comment: If you still needs to run this as root or sudo and use the home directory of a specific user, you can use a commandline argument and pass the desired username as a variable and fetch it into the place where ``whoami`` resides!

Answer (score -1):

Dynamic_Path="/home/$(whoami)/$SCRIPT_PATH"